# Why do white spaces get removed from label name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am writing code for a matrix in the d3 javascript library. I want some of the labels to be indented but adding spaces in font don't show. For example: "_____word" just shows as "word". (___ are spaces)

I am using :
http://bl.ocks.org/ianyfchang/8119685

```
rowLabel = ['word','word2' ];
colLabel = ['word3','word4','word5'];
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code with an example

Comment: I could swear that this was a duplicate, since it's a very common issue... However, I still didn't find the exact dupe. When I find it I'll remove my answer and close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preserving the white spaces in that labels you have to set the texts' `white-space` to [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

So, in that bl.ocks:

```
 text {
     white-space: pre;
 }
```

Here is the bl.ocks with that change, I added some random spaces in the labels: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/c384495d0e1982d2c3126d44a6d88293/6a822b8abceb9861af31d16fcf7625631c3f5eac